# preg_match get sentences provided in a format

Tags: preg-match

I have a text format in my db as :

```
Name : John Thompson
Address : 123 street abc state xyz country
```

How do I get value for Name i.e : Johan Thompson via preg_match?
I am trying to avoid long procedures of exploding and all as I will be getting other things besides Name and Address as-well.

I need to have simple regular expression that can get me a string containing sentence afer Name :, Address : and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply put:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/^(?P<propname>[^:]+):\s*(?P<propval>.*)$/m', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

This regex matches anything before the colon and captures it in `propname` and the rest to the line end will be captured in `propval`.
The resulting structure will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name : John Thompson
            [propname] => Name 
            [1] => Name 
            [propval] => John Thompson
            [2] => John Thompson
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Address : 123 street abc state xyz country
            [propname] => Address 
            [1] => Address 
            [propval] => 123 street abc state xyz country
            [2] => 123 street abc state xyz country
        )
)
```

As this is a simple regex, i assume, you are not familiar with regular expressions, so I strongly recommend reading [J.F. Friedl - Mastering Regular expressions](http://regex.info/), you will soon and easy craft wonderful expressions :-)